# Drawing a rectangle of 4cm in the south center of the titlepage?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I need to update a custom Beamer theme and I need to draw a rectangle on the bottom of the titlepage. The theme is [published on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/european-commission/qtzkhyvfxbrw) if you want to play with it.

The current title page roughly looks like this:

[image]

The Beamer template `title page` is currently defined a such:

```
% Title page - The first page of the presentation
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{ec}[1][]
{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{titlepage}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \coordinate (SW) at (current page.south west);
            \coordinate (SE) at (current page.south east);
            \coordinate (NW) at (current page.north west);
            \coordinate (NE) at (current page.north east);

            \fill[color=ecmain,anchor=south west] (SW) rectangle (13,2.4);
            \fill[color=ecaccentyellow] (1,-6) rectangle (1.05, 1);

            \node[ecaccentyellow,anchor=north west,font=\LARGE] (title) at (1,1) {
                \inserttitle
            };
            \node[ecaccentyellow,anchor=north west,font=\Large] (subtitle) at (1,0) {
                \insertsubtitle
            };
            \node[white,anchor=south east,align=right] (author) at (12.5,-5.5) {
                \texttt{\insertauthor}\\\texttt{\insertinstitute}\\\texttt{\insertdate}
            };
            % \useasboundingbox (SW) rectangle (NE);
            % \draw [help lines] (SW) grid (NE);
        \end{tikzpicture}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \node[anchor=north] at (current page.north) {
                \includegraphics[trim=0 0 0 3mm,scale=0.25]{logo-ce-en}
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{beamercolorbox}

    \setcounter{framenumber}{0}
}
```

I would like to add a rectangle in the bottom of that page. The rectangle needs to be 4cm wide and 1cm of height and perfectly centered in the bottom, so the title page would look like this:

[image]

I tried many things using `\draw`, but I'm unable to do it properly.

Do you have a piece of advice here?

Comment: Unrelated to your question (that I do not know how to answer), but notice that the "Date" is sitting badly (too low) in its box.

Comment: `\draw[shift=(current page.south)] (-2cm,0) rectangle (2cm,1cm);`? Add `yshift=\pgflinewidth` if you need the bottom line to show up.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Qrrbrbirlbel ! It works.

I linked to the Overleaf theme so people can edit/use the theme, I guess it's a better solution since copying the whole theme would have been too much in this case.

Comment: @mickep It's excalidraw's fault, it is supposed to be perfectly centered, just like other boxes. I'm impressed you noticed it :)